# How to perform a for-each loop over all the files under a specified path?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

The following command attempts to enumerate all `*.txt` files in the current directory and process them one by one:

```
for line in "find . -iname '*.txt'"; do 
     echo $line
     ls -l $line; 
done
```

Why do I get the following error?:

```
ls: invalid option -- 'e'
Try `ls --help' for more information.
```

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Here is a better way to loop over files as it handles spaces and newlines in file names:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f -iname "*.txt" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' line; do
    echo "$line"
    ls -l "$line"    
done
```

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work when the script containing this snippet is called from within a cronjob @reboot. It complains about the -d flag of the read command and then fails to execute. Otherwise it works great.

Comment: Works on bash, not on sh.

Comment: @jww Works for me on macOS Sierra, `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)`

Answer (score 19):

The `for`-loop will iterate over each (space separated) entry on the provided string.

You do not actually execute the `find` command, but provide it is as string (which gets iterated by the `for`-loop).
Instead of the double quotes use either backticks or `$()`:

```
for line in $(find . -iname '*.txt'); do 
     echo "$line"
     ls -l "$line"
done
```

Furthermore, if your file paths/names contains spaces this method fails (since the `for`-loop iterates over space separated entries). Instead it is better to use the method described in [dogbanes answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15066129/246263).

---

To clarify your error:

As said, `for line in "find . -iname '*.txt'";`  iterates over all space separated entries, which are:

- find
- .
- -iname
- '*.txt' (I think...)

The first two do not result in an error (besides the undesired behavior), but the third is problematic as it executes:

```
ls -l -iname
```

A lot of (bash) commands can combine single character options, so `-iname` is the same as `-i -n -a -m -e`. And voila: your `invalid option -- 'e'` error!

Comment: If there are spaces in the name, it will appear as two separate entries in the list that the for loop iterates over.

Answer (score 18):

More compact version working with spaces and newlines in the file name:

```
find . -iname '*.txt' -exec sh -c 'echo "{}" ; ls -l "{}"' \;
```

Comment: This answer is much simpler and it works in both Bash and the simpler sh (Ash) shells.

Comment: This answer is **seriously buggy** right now; a malicious filename can run arbitrary code. Consider what happens if someone created `$(rm -rf ~).txt`, or `"; rm -rf ~; echo ".txt` (with the double-quotes as literal part of the filenames).

Comment: The safe (and more efficient) way to write this would be `find . -iname '*.txt' -exec sh -c 'for arg in "$@"; do echo "$arg"; ls -l "$arg"; done' _ {} +`

Answer (score 2):

Use [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution) instead of quotes to execute find instead of passing the command as a string:

```
for line in $(find . -iname '*.txt'); do 
     echo $line
     ls -l $line; 
done
```

Comment: if you have a file named "single file" you will get two `$lines` in the loop. One for "single" another for "file".

Comment: See [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) re: `for line in $(...anything...)`, and [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo) re: `echo $line`. For the latter, also see [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)