# Remove duplicate filename extensions

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I have thousands of files named something like filename.gz.gz.gz.gz.gz.gz.gz.gz.gz.gz.gz

I am using the find command like this `find . -name "*.gz*"` to locate these files and either use `-exec` or pipe to xargs and have some magic command to clean this mess, so that I end up with filename.gz

Someone please help me come up with this magic command that would remove the unneeded instances of `.gz`. I had tried experimenting with `sed 's/\.gz//'` and `sed 's/(\.gz)//'` but they do not seem to work (or to be more honest, I am not very familiar with sed). I do not have to use sed by the way, any solution that would help solve this problem would be welcome :-)

Comment: Another question, is the instances of .gz extension multiplied a certain amount of times?

Comment: Is this a good idea? How was your `filename.gz.gz` created? `gzip` has guards against accidentally creating it. If you circumvent these via something like `gzip -c $1 > $1.gz`, buried in some script, then renaming your files will give you grief.

Answer (score 4):

one way with find and awk:

```
find $(pwd) -name '*.gz'|awk '{n=$0;sub(/(\.gz)+$/,".gz",n);print "mv",$0,n}'|sh
```

Note:

- I assume there is no special chars (like spaces...) in your filename. If there were, you need quote the filename in mv command.
- I added a `$(pwd)` to get the absolute path of found name.
- you can remove the ending `|sh` to check generated `mv ... ....` cmd, if it is correct.
- If everything looks good, add the `|sh` to execute the `mv`

see example here:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for an off-topic comment but I have to ask, what did you use to record that animated GIF, `byzanz`? It looks really nice.

Comment: @nwk yes, it is byzanz, with my own wrapper. https://github.com/sk1418/myScripts/blob/master/shell/recWin.sh

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
ls a.gz.gz.gz |sed -r 's/(\.gz)+/.gz/'
```

or without the regex flag

```
ls a.gz.gz.gz |sed 's/\(\.gz\)\+/.gz/'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls *.gz | perl -ne '/((.*?.gz).*)/; print "mv $1 $2\n"'
```

It will print shell commands to rename your files, it won't execute those commands. It is safe. To execute it, you can save it to file and execute, or simply pipe to shell:

```
ls *.gz | ... | sh
```

`sed` is great for replacing text *inside* files.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name "*.gz.gz" | 
 while read f; do echo mv "$f" "$(sed -r 's/(\.gz)+$/.gz/' <<<"$f")"; done
```

This only previews the renaming (`mv`) command; remove the `echo` to perform actual renaming.

- Processes matching files in the current directory *tree*, as in the OP (and not just files located *directly* in the current directory).
- Limits matching to files that end in at least *2* `.gz` extensions (so as not to needlessly process files that end in just one).
- When determining the new name with `sed`, makes sure that substring `.gz` doesn't just match anywhere in the filename, but only as part of a contiguous sequence of `.gz` extensions at the *end* of the filename.
- Handles filenames with special chars. such as embedded spaces correctly (with the exception of filenames with embedded newlines.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `bash` string substitution:

```
for file in *.gz.gz; do
    mv "${file}" "${file%%.*}.gz"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Using bash string substitution:

```
for f in *.gz.gz; do
    mv "$f" "${f%%.gz.gz*}.gz"
done
```

This is a slight modification of jaypal's nice answer (which would fail if any of your files had a period as part of its name, such as `foo.c.gz.gz`). <sup>(Mine is not perfect, either)</sup> Note the use of double-quotes, which protects against filenames with "bad" characters, such as spaces or stars.

If you wish to use `find` to process an entire directory tree, the variant is:

```
find . -name \*.gz.gz | \
while read f; do
    mv "$f" "${f%%.gz.gz*}.gz"
done
```

And if you are fussy and need to handle filenames with embedded newlines, change the `while read` to `while IFS= read -r -d $'\0'`, and add a `-print0` to `find`; see [How do I use a for-each loop to iterate over file paths output by the find utility in the shell / Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065010/how-to-do-for-each-file-using-find-in-shell-bash).

But is this renaming a good idea? How was your `filename.gz.gz` created? `gzip` has guards against accidentally doing so. If you circumvent these via something like `gzip -c $1 > $1.gz`, buried in some script, then renaming these files will give you grief.

Comment: While this is indeed an improvement over stripping the extensions with `%%.*`, it could still strip too much, e.g. with `somefile.gz.gz.other.gz.gz`. Also, as with many other answers here, you only process files located _directly_ in the current directory, whereas the OP - due to use of `find` - processes the entire directory _subtree_.

Comment: @mklement0: Agreed. Wrt `.other.` I had already added a comment. Will add something like `find ... -print0 | ...` shortly.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
echo *.gz | sed -r 's/^([^.]*)(\.gz){2,}$/mv -v & \1\2/e'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way with rename:

```
find . -iname '*.gz.gz' -exec rename -n 's/(\.\w+)\1+$/$1/' {} +
```

When happy with the results remove `-n` (dry-run) option.