# Bash loop over directory tree with ffmpeg, wrong spaces?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, find

I am trying to interate over multiple video files that are grouped in directories, and ffmpeg returns errors about paths, it seems like paths are broken, end at first space. Can you point me too what is the problem here? Files and directories have spaces.

```
$ for f in $(find -type f -name *.mkv); do ffmpeg -n -i "$f" -c:v copy "~/Pobrane/$f" ; done
```

Loop splits paths by space and takes words as entries. How to fix this?

```
$ for f in $(find -type f -name *.mkv); do echo "$f"; done
./homeworks/2017-04-03
00-54-57
homework3b.mkv
./homeworks/2017-04-03
00-21-36
homework1.mkv
./homeworks/2017-04-03
```

Comment: [Don't Read Lines With `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). Also see [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: (Another useful resource is [Using Find](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Replacing the Loop

Use

```
find -type f -name '*.mkv' -exec ffmpeg -n -i {} -c:v copy ~/Pobrane/{} \;
```

`-exec` executes the following `ffmpeg` command for each of the found paths, replacing `{}` with the current path. The `;` informs `find` that the `ffmpeg` command ends there.

Quote `'*.mkv'` in order to pass the literal string to `find`, which then searches for files ending with `*.mkv`. If you do not quote the string and have some mkv files laying around in your working directory, the shell will expand the unquoted `*.mkv` resulting in `find -type f -name firstFile.mkv secondFile.mkv ...` before starting `find`.

Do *not* quote `~`. The unquoted `~` expands to your home directory (probably `/home/yourname`) but the quoted `'~'` is a directory/file with the literal name `~` .

## Creating Parent Directories

> How would I add `mkdir -p` before the ffmpeg call?

You could wrap the `mkdir` and `ffmpeg` in one function and [execute the function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4321522/6770384):

```
myFunction() {
    mkdir -p "$(dirname "$1")"
    ffmpeg -n -i "$1" -c:v copy ~/Pobrane/"$1"
}
export -f myFunction

find -type f -name '*.mkv' -exec bash -c 'myFunction "$0"' {} \;
```

or [use a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15066129/6770384):

```
find . -type f -iname "*.txt" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
    mkdir -p "$(dirname "$file")"
    ffmpeg -n -i "$file" -c:v copy ~/Pobrane/"$file" 
done
```

Comment: Nevermind I just tried it myself and it doesn't seem to make a difference.