# How can stop group of containers with regex in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

**Question:**

How can I stop containers that their names start with `server-`?

**Containers**

```
> sudo docker-compose ps
                        Name                                      Command               State                        Ports                     
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
server-myservername1_1                                          some commands           Up                                               
server-myservername2_1                                          some commands           Up                                                     
server-myservername3_1                                          some commands           Up                            
server-myservername4_1                                          some commands           Up                     
server-myservername5_1                                          some commands           Up                   
server-myservername6_1                                          some commands           Up                                  
console-myconsolename1_1                                        some commands           Up                             
console-myconsolename2_1                                        some commands           Up
```

Comment: Using bash loop commands [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065010/how-to-perform-a-for-each-loop-over-all-the-files-under-a-specified-path).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First check the output of below command if it's gives the names of only those containers that you have to stop

```
docker-compose ps | grep server | awk '{print $1}'
```

If the list is right, then run

```
docker stop $(docker-compose ps | grep server | awk '{print $1}')
```

P.S. I haven't tested the above command. Let me know if it doesn't

Comment: Thanks a lot, I use this command ``sudo docker-compose stop $(docker-compose ps --services | grep server |awk '{print $1}')
``

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use **--filter** option of ps command
Suppose you wanna look for 3 containers, which their names start with **site**

```
docker ps --filter name=site*
```

will show you stat of those three containers.
so use one of this to stop the containers

```
- docker ps --filter name=site* -aq | xargs docker stop
- docker stop $(docker ps --filter name=site* -aq)
```